# RequireJS with CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, commonjs

Using RequireJS with CommonJS modules, what happens when I do this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    //Put traditional CommonJS module content here

    var simpleCommonJSModule = require('simple-commonjs-module');   

    module.exports = new String('foo');

   return {
        //return empty object along with using module.exports
   }
});
```

if I return something, I assume the module.exports will be ignored? Or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you return something module.exports will ignored.

Here's a snippet from the original documentation.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
       var a = require('a'),
           b = require('b');

       //Return the module value
       return function () {};
    } 
);
```

If you want to use the `exports` CJS style here's you do it

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
   exports.foo = function () {
       return a.bar();
   };
});
```

Comment: yeah so I guess is this is how AMD/RequireJS shims CommonJS modules, simply by wrapping them with the define function and then returning a value after the exports statements